# How to suppress stdout and stderr in bash

Tags: bash

I was trying to make a little script when I realized that the output redirection `&>` doesn't work inside a script. If I write in the terminal

```
dpkg -s firefox &> /dev/null
```

or

```
dpkg -s firefox 2>&1 /dev/null
```

I get no output, but if I insert it in a script it will display the output. The strange thing is that if I write **inside** the script

```
dpkg -s firefox 1> /dev/null
```

or

```
dpkg -s firefox 2> /dev/null
```

the output of the command is suppressed. How can I suppress both `stderr` and `stdout`?

Comment: Are you sure the script is being run with `/bin/bash`, not `/bin/sh`? What does the `#!` line look like? `&>` is a `bash` extension, so it may not work in other shells.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`&>` is a bash extension: `&>filename` is equivalent to the POSIX standard `>filename 2>&1`.

Make sure the script begins with `#!/bin/bash`, so it's able to use `bash` extensions. `#!/bin/sh` runs a different shell (or it may be a link to `bash`, but when it sees that it's run with this name it switches to a more POSIX-compatible mode).

You almost got it right with `2>&1 >/dev/null`, but the order is important. Redirections are executed from left to right, so your version copies the old `stdout` to `stderr`, then redirects `stdout` to `/dev/null`. The correct, portable way to redirect both `stderr` and `stdout` to `/dev/null` is:

```
>/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 10):

Make file descriptor 2 (stderr) write to where File descriptor 1 (stdout) is writing

```
dpkg -s firefox >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This will suppress both sources.

Answer (score 2):

Additional guidance to stderr (error) and stdout (output) suppression

**Suppress output only**

```
dpkg -s firefox 1> /dev/null
dpkg -s firefox > /dev/null
```

**Suppress error only**

```
dpkg -s firefox 2> /dev/null
```

**Suppress output and error**

```
dpkg -s firefox >/dev/null 2>&1

# You can read this as 2 (stderr) goes wherever 1 (stdoutput) goes. i.e. /dev/null.
```

`/dev/null` is the the blackhole in unix, where if anything that is sent is gone forever.